# How to validate format of data?

Tags: python, dataframe

I need to validate some data like this

```
x = "X180Y50"
```

The problem is the user is submitting the data, and the user may enter data in other formats. I need to check if the data is in this format:

```
x = X%Y%
```

The % can be any number between 0  and 180.

Comment: [This is an excellent library](https://pypi.org/project/pandas-validation/) which is used to validate DataFrames.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use regular expression

```py
import re

def validate(text):
   PATTERN = r'X(\d|\d\d|1[0-7]\d|180)Y(\d|\d\d|1[0-7]\d|180)'
   REGEX_OBJECT = re.compile(PATTERN)

   is_matched = REGEX_OBJECT.match(text)
   if is_matched:
      return True
   else:
      return False
```

You can use https://regex101.com/ to test the regular expression

Answer (score 2):

That'd be easily validated with a regular expression and some additional logic.

```
import re

def is_xy(s):
    m = re.match("^X(\d+)Y(\d+)$", s)
    if not m:
        return False
    if not 0 <= int(m.group(1)) < 180:
        return False
    if not 0 <= int(m.group(2)) < 180:
        return False
    return True


for case in ["ASDF", "X11Y91", "X39521Y911", "4", "hello"]:
    print(case, is_xy(case))
```

prints out

```
ASDF False
X11Y91 True
X39521Y911 False
4 False
hello False
```

Comment: thank you for your help, can you change it so if its false it passes and if its true it return it. i hop you have nice day :)